# Pick up date, add day and put back

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I want to pick up date from screen, add 1 day and put back to screen.

```
<input type='text'value='20101231' id='from_date'>

<script>    

    function date_move(direction){              
        var from_date = document.getElementById('from_date').value;                 
        var YYYY = from_date.substring(0,4);
        var MM = from_date.substring(4,6);
        var DD = from_date.substring(6,8);      
        var jsCurDate = new Date( parseInt(YYYY,10), parseInt(MM,10)-1, parseInt(DD,10) );
        var newDate = addOrSubtracDays(jsCurDate,direction)             
        document.getElementById('from_date').value = newDate;   
    }


    function addOrSubtracDays(jsCurDate,daysOffset){        
        var daylength= 1*24*60*60*1000;
        var newDate = new Date(jsCurDate + daylength);
        alert(newDate)      
    }


date_move(+1);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `element.value` to get the contents of an arbitrary HTML element, `.value` only works on form elements. Use `element.innerHTML` instead:

```
var from_date = document.getElementById('from_date').innerHTML;
```

Also, your use of [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is wrong. I think [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is more clear:

```
var YYYY = from_date.substr(0,4);
var MM = from_date.substr(4,2);
var DD = from_date.substr(6,2);
```

In `addOrSubtracDays` (shouldn't that be `addOrSubtractDays`?) you want the number of milliseconds, so you should call [`Date.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). Moreover, you actually want to `return` the new value:

```
return new Date(jsCurDate.getTime() + daylength * daysOffset);
```

When changing `#from_date` you probably want your date to be in the same format. For this, I extend `Date`'s prototype with a new method (and `String` with a helper function):

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (length, character) {
    return new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' ') + this;
};

Date.prototype.toFormattedString = function () {
    return [String(this.getFullYear()),
            String(this.getMonth()+1).padLeft(2, '0'),
            String(this.getDate()).padLeft(2, '0')].join('');
};
```

After this, we can simply call `toFormattedString`:

```
document.getElementById('from_date').innerHTML = newDate.toFormattedString();
```

BTW, you don't need to explicitly convert `YYYY`, `MM` and `DD` to integers with base 10; those are converted automatically (without assuming a string beginning with `0` is an octal number):

```
var jsCurDate = new Date(YYYY, MM - 1, DD);
```

For the sake of clarity, the complete script now reads:

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (length, character) {
    return new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' ') + this;
};

Date.prototype.toFormattedString = function () {
    return [String(this.getFullYear()),
            String(this.getMonth()+1).padLeft(2, '0'),
            String(this.getDate()).padLeft(2, '0')].join('');
};

function date_move(direction){
    var from_date = document.getElementById('from_date').innerHTML;
    var YYYY = from_date.substr(0,4);
    var MM = from_date.substr(4,2);
    var DD = from_date.substr(6,2);
    var jsCurDate = new Date(YYYY, MM - 1, DD);
    var newDate = addOrSubtracDays(jsCurDate, direction);
    document.getElementById('from_date').innerHTML = newDate.toFormattedString();
}

function addOrSubtracDays(jsCurDate, daysOffset){
    var daylength= 1*24*60*60*1000;
    return new Date(jsCurDate.getTime() + daylength * daysOffset);
}

date_move(+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the only thing you are missing in that code is:

```
function addOrSubtracDays(jsCurDate,daysOffset){        
    var daylength= 1*24*60*60*1000;
    var newDate = new Date(jsCurDate+(daylength*daysOffset));
    document.getElementById('from_date').value = newDate; //<-THIS LINE
}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry I read badly... never mind

Comment: you are correct, that was missing, but there are other issues as well.